# Using Ruby loops to parse an XML doc

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, loops

Say I have the following XML doc. I'm using Ruby 1.9.3, Rails 3.2.6, and Nokogiri 1.5.5 to parse the XML into a database. I want to be able to loop through the XML tags and pick out elements in the correct order.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<RandomTag>
    <library name='Favorite Books'>
        <book ISBN="11342343">
          <title>TKAM</title>
          <description>Desc1</description>
          <author>H Lee</author>
        </book>
        <book ISBN="989894781234">
          <title>Catcher in the Rye</title>
          <description>Desc2</description>
          <author>JD S</author>
        </book>
    </library>
    <library name='Other Books'>
        <book ISBN="123456789">
          <title>Murphy\'s Gambit</title>
          <description>Desc3</description>
          <author>Syne M</author>
        </book>
    </library>
</RandomTag>
```

I'm using a loop similar to the following to iterate through:

```
f = File.open(args[:file])
doc = Nokogiri::XML(f)
f.close

doc.css('library').each do |node|
  children = node.children
  lib = {"name" => node['name']}
  Library.create(lib)

  doc.css('book').each do |n|
    churn = n.children
    book = {#book elements}
    Book.create(book)
  end
end
```

So I'm basically searching for a library, and then once I find it, I'm searching for all books within that library. The problem with my current code is that the .css() method searches until EOF. So the inner 'book' loop hits on every single book, regardless of which library it resides in. Additionally, once I hit a second library, the 'book' loop again starts from beginning of the doc and continues through every book. End result is I get the correct number of libraries with the right name, but every library has every book. I need a way to stop searching for books (break from the inner loop) when I hit a new 'library' tag.

Is there a different method than .css() that will do this? Is there some way to write in a break statement in my loop to exit upon a given situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're finding all books because you're calling

```
doc.css('book')
```

Which by definition searches for any book in the document. If you only want to find books inside a certain element then call `.css` on that:

```
doc.css('library').each do |library_node|
  library_node.css('book').each do |book_node|
    #only iterates on the books inside that library
  end
end
```

Comment: Of course. Probably should have figured that one out myself haha...Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

what you see here is an iterator. the method iterates over all the attribute it finds.

if nokogiri supports the enumerable module, there are several other methods that you can use:

http://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable

in your case, you would use find to just use the first matching element.

Comment: Okay, so I use .find to search for the first library. Now I have it. Now I need to iterate (enumerate?) through all of the books until I hit the next library tag. I use .find again to get the first book. I put this .find method in a loop to find all the books. How do I stop finding books and continue finding libraries?